# Display the query result in many text boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
msgid   title  body              sendat
   1       new    this is body      11/11/2011
   2       old    ths is is         12/11/2011
```

I am doing a query and displaying the message with MSGID 1 in a grid
view. I want to display it in text boxes.

```
   title:   new
   body:    this is body
   sendat:  11/11/2011
```

How can this be done?

Comment: can you show your code and query on how you are loading the data in the Grid?

Comment: If you don't like the Grid format, your best bet would be to use a Listview or a repeater.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should be using the `<asp:Repeater/>` control and providing the UI you specifically want in the `<ItemTemplate>` section. Repeater doesn't get the love it deserves =D

If you need to specifically attach data, I would recommend attaching to the `repeater.ItemCreated` event.

Comment: Repeaters are designed for listings of information that isn't always in a standard pure horizontal format. For example, these answers on your question can be emulated with an ASP.NET repeater

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is probably to use a Repeater control.  Google for asp.net repeater will give you TONS of information on how to set one up.